# An open source SQL database for the list of towns cities by country?

Tags: sql, database, open-source, countries

I am looking for a list of towns, cities by country (the countries I mean here are all countries that exist on planet Earth). Is there any open-source SQL database available online which I can download and use, or any geography social network sites APIs I can use?

Or is it something I have to make it up myself? - I hope not!

Answer (score 2):

There is a sample database for PostgreSQL with that information. I don't know how outdated it is, though...

It's hosted in http://pgfoundry.org/projects/dbsamples/.

Comment: too bad it's using the iso 3char code

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

> The downloadable file contains a list
>   of all towns, administrative divisions
>   and agglomerations with their current
>   population, their English name (if not
>   equal to the international name) and
>   parent country. The international
>   names are displayed in UTF-8 format,
>   which means that special characters
>   which are not displayable with a
>   normal text editor, are displayed as
>   two characters. A freeware text editor
>   that can read UTF-8 characters is
>   UniRed. When opening the file with
>   UniRed you have to specify the charset
>   UTF-8.

http://www.world-gazetteer.com/wg.php?x=1129163518&men=stdl&lng=en&gln=xx&dat=32&srt=npan&col=aohdq

Comment: doesn't work anymore...

Answer (score 0):

This gives you the SQL to insert a list of countries into a table - 239 of them:

http://www.sqldumpster.com/databases/geographic/

Look for "Countries (and ISO codes)"

Didn't find anything obvious for the cities and towns.  Maybe you can use the countries list an make a crawler to find them.