# How to make the cities/countries dropdown like facebook does?

Tags: drop-down-menu, country, city

See the screenshot here:
[image: http://media-cdn.pinterest.com/upload/185773553348981093_6T1oUT9E.jpg]

I'd like the user to just type a city or country name and the autocompleter will show suggested items.

How should I start for creating it?
Are there any API(s) or web services for me to call?
Where can I find the database of all cities/countries in the world?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this would be the best database for your situation, check it out:

http://www.geodatasource.com/cities-free.html

Comment: Thanks Ali, it's really useful to me.

Comment: what about flagging it as the right answer and giving me a vote up

Comment: Link is now broken

Answer (score 2):

You first need a autocomplete plugin.
I recommend to use the [jQuery-Ui Auto Complete Plugin](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/).

The database could as example be [this](http://www.maxmind.com/app/worldcities), but eventually try to search a bit for yourself.
There was already a [question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4140099/an-open-source-sql-database-for-the-list-of-towns-cities-by-country) about a database for cities of the world.
A simple text file with all cities may also be [this](http://www.world-gazetteer.com/wg.php?x=1129163518&men=stdl&lng=en&gln=xx&dat=32&srt=npan&col=aohdq).
There are very much of those libraries, but you have to chose the right one for you.

Answer (score 0):

My solution may not be the best, but it's a starting point:
Google a list with all countries (ISO-Standard), paste it into a txt-file. Then you can simply read that file with PHP an create a select menu with the contents of the file.
It does not incorporate the cities, but maybe it helps you in some way.